# Loading a RSA private key from memory using libxmlsec

Tags: c++, openssl, rsa, libxml2, xmlsec

I'm currently using [libxmlsec](http://www.aleksey.com/xmlsec/index.html) into my C++ software and I try to load a RSA private key from memory. To do this, I searched trough the API and found [this function](http://www.aleksey.com/xmlsec/api/xmlsec-openssl-app.html#XMLSECOPENSSLAPPKEYLOADMEMORY).

It takes binary data, a size, a format string and several PEM-callback related parameters.

When I call the function, it just stucks, uses 100% of the CPU time and never returns. Quite annoying, because I have no way of finding out what is wrong.

Here is my code:

```
d_xmlsec_dsig_context->signKey =
    xmlSecCryptoAppKeyLoadMemory(
        reinterpret_cast<const xmlSecByte*>(data),
        static_cast<xmlSecSize>(datalen), 
        xmlSecKeyDataFormatBinary,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL
    );
```

**`data`** is a `const char*` pointing to the raw bytes of my RSA key (using **`i2d_RSAPrivateKey()`**, from *OpenSSL*) and **`datalen`** the size of **`data`**.

My **test** private key doesn't have a passphrase so I decided not to use the callbacks for the time being.

Has someone already done something similar ? Do you guys see anything that I could change/test to get forward on this problem ?

I just discovered the library on yesterday, so I might miss something obvious here; I just can't see it.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the format of **`data`** to PEM, using the OpenSSL function **`PEM_write_bio_RSAPrivateKey()`** and changed the third argument to the call to **`xmlSecCryptoAppKeyLoadMemory()`** so it matches the new format.

The new code is:

```
d_xmlsec_dsig_context->signKey =
xmlSecCryptoAppKeyLoadMemory(
    reinterpret_cast<const xmlSecByte*>(data), // data is now in PEM format
    static_cast<xmlSecSize>(datalen), 
    xmlSecKeyDataFormatPem, // Updated
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL
);
```

And since then, everything works: the call does no longer get stuck.